# Does Unkar know the First Order is looking for BB-8?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, bb-8

After the First Order get orders to retrieve BB-8, we see Unkar offer an enormous payout for him. Does he know the First Order is looking for it, or is he just wanting the droid for the sake of having him?

Comment: As I never say, the more independent villains, the better!

Comment: While we never really see him get information about the droid from the first order, we could go off the fact that a BB unit (or any sort of droid) in that condition must be very valuable.  In fact, when Rey first runs into him, we see that another junker is trying to collect it.

Comment: When Rey refuses to sell BB-8, doesn't Unkar immediately shut down shop and radio to somebody that he couldn't buy the droid? That suggests that, at the very least, he was working with somebody to obtain BB-8, and specifically BB-8.

Comment: @PeregrineRook: Didn't Unkar radio to actually arrange others to take it? I only saw the movie once, but I didn't get the impression he even knew of the droid until Rey shows up with it to turn in her salvage. And when she refuses to sell it, he simply arranges alternative methods to acquire it.

Comment: Plutt definitely didn't want to buy the droid simply for its inherent value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's abundantly clear that Plutt wasn't trying to buy BB-8 because of its inherent value but rather because he'd received information stating that someone was willing to pay very good money for a droid fitting BB-8's description. In both of the film's novelisations (and the script), he describes this info as having come from *"certain parties"* but it's unclear whether he knows or even cares who the actual buyer is going to be.

The fact that he doesn't mention that it's a *governmental* party that wishes to acquire the droid would seem to suggest that he was just told by another criminal.

> Plutt stuffed the booth drawer with ration packets. **“Certain parties have been asking around for a droid like that.”**
>   Certain parties? Who was Plutt talking about?
>   The drawer popped open on her side of the booth. At the sight of so much food, she reached down for a handful of packets.
>   “That’s my girl,” Plutt said. - <sub><sup>[Force Awakens: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

and

> “Oh, I’m not going to keep him for myself.” Plutt spoke absently as he
>   continued to stack full nutrition portions beside his seat. **“Certain
>   parties have been asking around about a droid like that. None of my
>   business what they want it for. Smart traders don’t delve deeply into
>   their customers’ motivations.”** He glanced over at her. “If I find out,
>   I’ll do you the courtesy of letting you know. Meanwhile, I’d like to
>   think this exchange’ll be good for both of us. That’s the best kind of
>   business, after all.” As he started placing packets into the transfer
>   drawer, she moved to take them. <sub><sup>[Force Awakens: Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>

---

You may wish to note that that the [Guavian Death Gang](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Guavian_Death_Gang) have apparently received (updated) info directly stating that it's the First Order that's after the droid. It's certainly possible that the Guavians are the ones who told Plutt to look out for BB-8.

> Leech raised his bayoneted rifle—but Bala-Tik blocked his line of
>   fire. “That BB unit,” he said to Han, eyeing the droid. “The First
>   Order is looking for one just like it. And two fugitives.”